# Some faces appear darker BUT normals are okay

Tags: mesh, faces

I have noticed that sometimes when I model some objects, some face later on appear to be a bit darker than others. Especially after texturing.
I have checked the normals and they are pointing in the right direction. I have tried recalculating normals to see whether it fixes anything but no luck.

I also tried rotating the objects to see whether it is an issue with lighting. Sadly it isn't.

Also, this isn't caused by a normal or bump texture because the problem appears even before I start adding those. 
This is the third model I am experiencing this on.

I will appreciate even just an explanation to understand why this happens.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Image doesn't  point the defects according to your question

Comment: Would you mind upload your file?

Comment: The defect is in the lower part of the plank in the image. It has exactly the same texture as the upper part and the sides, yet it appears to be significantly darker.

Answer (score 1):

when this happens to me i just select it and apply "faces>shade flat". if someone has a better answer please share.

Comment: You are right. Making it to shade as flat fixes it. But what happens when I need a smooth face.
So this indeed is an issue. I'm glad I'm not the only one experiencing it because I thought I did something wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this isn't normals, it's smooth shading accompanied with comparably low polygon count, look at the image, all three cylinders have identical mesh, the one to the left has flat shading, the one in the middle smooth, the one to the right is also smooth but with Edge Split modifier, I believe you're interested in the result to the right.
[image]

**SOLUTION:**

you just need to add Edge Split modifier, the downside is making the edges that are below the angle threshold, very unrealistically sharp, but that's part of the price paid when working with low poly, if this result is not an acceptable option:
**The other solution** is to make some edge loops near the edges that are affected by the smooth shading, check the following images.
This is the result by adding some edge loops, or in general more polygons.
[image]
And this is how the mesh looks like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Normal Autosmooth]

You can try going to *Object Data Properties > Normal > Auto Smooth*
as shown in the photo below.

That might solve your issue as it solved mine.